# Where can i see the perfino agent logs

Tags: performance, performance-testing, perfino

I couldn't able to setup the perfino java agent in windows server standard.

Passed the "-javaagent:E:\perfino\perfino.jar=server=172.16.11.160,port=8090,name=webserver1" VM argument to tomcat7,  my application launched successfully but when I verify the perfino server (172.16.11.160:8090) agent is not listing.

In my tocat logs(info) I saw only "perfino> Agent initialized (build version 26704)" this message, not sure how to debug more.

Appricate your help in advance.

Cheers,
Ashok

Comment: Finally I can able to figure it out the issue, looks like its bug in the build version 26704

Agent connected successfully with default port which is 8020, other than its failing :)

Answer (score 2):

The port for connections from VMs is configured with the `vmPort` option in perfino.properties.

By default, it is set to 8847. If you configure a different port, you have to add the `,port=nnnnn` option to the `-javaagent` parameter. In that case, the setting in perfino.properties and the part value on the agent parameter have to match, otherwise no connection can be made.